# How to specify `{$LIBSUFFIX AUTO}` in `dcc32 --lib-suffix`?

Tags: delphi

Since RAD Studio Sydney 10.4, the `$LIBSUFFIX` directive allows the use of an `AUTO` option in package file.

It will appear in package file as

```
{$LIBSUFFIX AUTO}
```

When build the package in RAD Studio 11, the package output file will have name like `*280.bpl`.

The `dcc32` command line compiler has an option `--lib-suffix` to override the LIBSUFFIX, when I run `dcc32 --lib-suffix AUTO ...`, the BPL file become `*AUTO.bpl` instead of `*280.bpl`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the AUTO is resolved by the IDE and not the compiler.

Comment: If the .dpk file has `{$LIBSUFFIX AUTO}` and using dcc32 to build, it will append the correct package version number to the `.bpl` file.  So I think the AUTO is resolved by dcc32 compiler instead of IDE.  I suspect the `dcc32` does not resolve AUTO in `--lib-suffix`.

Comment: OK, that is also a possibility.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang "*I suspect the `dcc32` does not resolve AUTO in `--lib-suffix`*" - There are a number of tickets in Quality Portal related to `libsuffix auto`, so this would not surprise me.